# Replace memcache variable BEFORE time expires using PHP

Tags: php, memcached

Sorry for the simple question, just want to make sure I'm doing this right. How do I check a memcache variable expiration date and query my database again only if the expiration date hasn't expired? Is `empty()` all that is needed?

here's my code:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

$dbQuery=$memcache->get('dbQuery');

if(empty($dbQuery)){
    $dbQuery=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE ...");
    $memcache->set('dbQuery', $dbQuery, false, 60*60);
    $dbQuery=$memcache->get('dbQuery');
}
else{
}
return $dbQuery;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it the following way:

```
$result = $memcache->get($some_key);

if( $result === false ) {
//set() key stuff goes here
}

return $result;
```

`get()` returns `FALSE` if the key is not found. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php